# Net Force on Individual Masses, or the entire system?

Tags: forces, homework-and-exercises

In the picture, would the net force on each individual mass take into account both masses or just the individual mass? For example, would the net force on the first mass be equal to $am_1 = F_{\text{net}}$ or would it be $a(m_1 + m_2)  = F_\text{net}$?

[image]

Comment: So you can treat them together if you add the total forces and divide it by the mass? Do we only add the magnitudes of the forces, which therefore gives us the magnitude of the acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a whole answer, which follows below, but I want to preface by saying this:  When you're solving net force problems, it's very helpful to identify your system.  If you *only* want to know the net force and/or acceleration of block 1, then your system is just block 1.  In one of my intro physics classes, I was even taught to draw a loop around my system in the diagram, just as a double check.  Once you have identified your system (e.g. the objects you choose to solve for) then *that* is the mass you want to be using in your net force equation.

When you're looking at the net force equation for single object, you want to only use the mass of that particular in your net force equation.  You can convince yourself of this by setting up a free body diagram for each object.  So in this situation, you would want to use $am_1=F_{net}$. However, the second equation that you wrote, $a(m_1+m_2)=F_{net}$, would work perfectly fine if you wanted to solve for the net force acting *on the entire two-block system*.  I wouldn't recommend that approach on a problem like this, but it is a valid approach in other situations.

EDIT:  In response to some comments on another answer, it is worth pointing out that if you use the second method, $F_{net}=(m_1+m_2)a$ to find the acceleration of the system (in this problem, or any other similar two-body problem), it will only give you the *magnitude* of the acceleration, because block one and block to are moving along different axes.  In order to find the *direction* of acceleration for each block, you would have to inspect your free-body diagrams for each block after solving for the magnitude.

Comment: but its impossible to write an equation for the entire two block system! Isn't it imperative that they are looked at separately?

Comment: This is why I said "I wouldn't recommend that approach on a problem like this."  My point was simply that it is possible (and often useful) to write a single net force equation for multiple objects.  That point is hardly worth a down-vote though.  I answered your question!  "In this situation, you would want to use $am_1=F_{net}$

Comment: Im sorry but I didn't down vote you! In fact I don't even have the "reputation" to even do so!

Comment: But thank you so much for your help!